# Powershell Get Replacement info from User Profile for all users

Tags: powershell, user-profile, user-profile-property

I want to extract info regarding Username and Replacements from the users profile properties for all users and have it written to a csv file.

Maybee through a powershell script so it can run in a scheduled task.

Being new to Powershell and SharePoint, I need some assistance!

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with replacements?

Comment: Hi anders In mysite under More information, we have 2 lines where you can add the name of your replacements (Not sure if this is default or if it is custom made for us). our users maintain this themself, and i would like to create a list where our users quickly can see who is replaceing who...

Comment: With "my site" do you mean your public profile (eg. <yourmysite>/person.aspx)? Could you supply a screenshot of this?

Comment: Hi anders
yes it´s mysite/person.aspx - sorry cannot find where to add files :-) in there you have the option to add replacements 
br K

Comment: you should be able to add images from the toolbar http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post I dont see the replacement stuff on my public profile

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this information consumed by some other application, you could just use a SQL view to grab the information you want: http://iedaddy.com/2012/03/sharepoint-2010sql-view-to-get-user-profile-property-bag-values/

Or if you're looking to use the timer to export the CSV for audit historical purposes here's a post from when I had to read a CSV into the UPS, obviously just reverse the process: http://iedaddy.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-updating-user-profile-properties-with-powershell/

Of course, if your using a timer job to kick off the process make sure you set your context to the mysite web app to grab an instance of the UPS.

Answer (score 0):

In this post: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.it/2012/06/powershell-get-list-of-users-that-use.html
I wrote a powershell script to get the users of my farm and print a custom property. You can use it and expand it to wrote the information in a CSV file.

Meanwhile this is the code of the post:

```
$url = "http://mysharepointsite/"
$site = Get-SPSite $url
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$pMgr = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$enum = $pMgr.GetEnumerator()

while ($enum.MoveNext()) {
  $currUser = $profiles.Current
  $name = $currUser.DisplayName
  $customProp = $currUser["MyCustomProperty"]
  Write-Host "$name;$customProp"
}
```

Comment: Referring to external blog posts is fine, but please also include a short description on what is there and how it works. External links tend to be more short-lived than our forum, and we want to keep as much info inside this site as possible.